# Adding Click event for Array Elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am new to javascript 
I have a multi dimensional array which has 'li' in it.  i want to add click event listener for all the li in my multidimensional array
my array is  like this

```
newItems = [ 
  [li.pL14, li, li.pR15], 
  [li.pL14, li, li.pR15], 
  [li.pL14, li, li.pL14], 
  [li, li.pR15, li.description], 
  [li.pL14, li, li.pR15], 
  [li.pL14, li]
]
```

Comment: Are you sure that array should'nt contain strings? If so -> `$( newItems.join(', ') ).click()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...Let your newItems is the MultiDimensional variable of element "li"

```
for(var i=0;i<newItems.length;i++)
{
  for(var j=0;j<newItems[i].length;j++)
  {
    newItems[i][j].addEventListener('click',function(){
      // Your On Click code

    },false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `newItems` contains arrays of Nodes, not strings.

Variant #1. Simple `for loop`:

```
for (var i = newItems.length; i--;) for (var j = newItems[i].length; j--;)
$(newItems[i][j]).click(function() {
    // click
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ymuHR/

Variant #2*. Flatten array and convert into jQuery collection:

```
$([].concat.apply([], newItems)).click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ymuHR/1/

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use map function of jquery

```
$.map( newItems , function( val, i ) {
            $('#'+val).click(function(){
                //do something.
            });
        });
```

I know its late. but it is new late for improvements. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="abc1"><a href="#">linl 01</a></div>
<div id="abc2"><a href="#">linl 02</a></div>
<div id="abc3"><a href="#">linl 02</a></div>
<div id="abc4"><a href="#">linl 02</a></div>
```

jQuery

```
var ids = ["#abc1", "#abc2", "#abc3", "#abc4"];
for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
    $(ids[i]).click(function(){
        $(this).find("a").css({
            'font-weight':'bold'
        });
    });
}
```