# Adding Click Event for Elements inside multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

A Explanation for what i am doing.

I have ul that have li that has visiting card in it and  the amout vary which . i want to add extra  li to show the description of the visting card that  i clicked. for ex if i clicked 1st 2nd or 3rd card i want to add new li in 4th place if i clicked 4th 5th or 6th then i want to add new li in 7th place.

For this i made  an function to split the li in to  multidimensional array having three li inside an array. and that mulidimensinal array is call chunks. now i got the write. but i am not able to appened the new li in my required place.

And i am getting this error TypeError: chunks[i] is undefined

And i given the code below

> chunks[i] is undefined

```
chunks = [ 
    [li.pL14, li, li.pR15], 
    [li.pL14, li, li.pR15], 
    [li.pL14, li, li.pR15], 
    [li.pL14, li, li.pR15], 
    [li.pL14, li, li.pR15]
]

for (var i=0; i<chunks.length; i++) {    
    for (var j=0; j<chunks[i].length; j++) {
        $(chunks[i][j]).click(function() {
             $(chunks[i][j]).append('<li class="description"> <div class="cardDesCont mT1Mi"></div></li>');
        });
    }
}
```

Why it that happening?

Comment: Why would you add a click event to every element? Use event delegation on the parent to handle it.

Comment: This would be the second time you asked this, what did'nt work from your [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739652/adding-click-event-for-array-elements-in-javasctipt) ?

Comment: What is `li` defined as?

Answer (score 1):

You have `i++` where you should have `j++`, in the inner loop. So you are incrementing `i` beyond the array bounds. Your code should be:

```
for (var i=0; i<chunks.length; i++) {   
    for (var j=0; j<chunks[i].length; j++) {
        // --------------------- HERE ^^^
        $(chunks[i][j]).click(function() {
            console.log('script works');
        });
    }
}
```